# Django - filtering over many to many fields

Tags: django, django-queryset

How can I filter over multiple many to many fields.
for example I've:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    ...


class Product(models.Model):
    shippers = models.ManyToManyField(Shipper)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    ...
```

With 
*products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)*
I will get query with list of products in category.
How to get list of all possible shippers for all products in the category? The second question is how to get all instances of manufacturers from this query.

Now extracting of manufacturers looks like

```
manufacturer_ids = products.values_list('manufacturer').distinct()
manufacturers = Manufacturer.objects.filter(id__in=manufacturer_ids)
```

But i believe that should be better way
Also I don't have any idea how to get list of all possible shippers from this query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all shippers of all products in a given Category:

```
shippers = Shipper.objects.filter(product__category=category)
```

It's possible that this will return duplicate values, so you can call `.distinct()` on it.

To get the manufacturers more neatly, you can do:

```
manufacturers = Manufacturer.objects.filter(products__in=products)
```

On the other hand, it seems more sensible to me to put the category field as a `ForeignKey` field on the `Product` model, rather than the other way round.